# access csv files in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
import pandas as pd
csv_path="D:/arun/datasets/US Presidential Data.csv"
data=pd.read_csv(csv_path)
```

It is working properly, but the following code getting this error:

```
import pandas as pd
csv_path="D:/arun/textmining/r files/twitter_data_sets/GST/GST-28-08-2017/10-10-2017.csv"
data=pd.read_csv(csv_path)

UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-a90c76559f26> in <module>()
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 csv_path="D:/arun/textmining/r files/twitter_data_sets/GST/GST-28-08-2017/10-10-2017.csv"
----> 3 data=pd.read_csv(csv_path)
```

Comment: You have a folder like `/r files/` in your `csv_path`. That `r` might be creating issues. You can try re-naming that folder to something else. It should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an encoding error. I hope `utf8` can handle that.
Try

```
import pandas as pd
csv_path="D:/arun/datasets/US Presidential Data.csv"
data=pd.read_csv(csv_path,encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`data = pd.read_csv(csv_path, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")`

Or

```
data = pd.read_csv(csv_path, encoding = "utf-8")
```

Comment: You can't accept both answers, you can accept one and upvote both